# Tumblr OAuth Callback URL

Tags: oauth, tumblr

I'm setting the oauth_callback URL in the request header, when I do this in Twitter, it works fine and the user is redirected to the callback URL.  But using Tumblr's API, the callback URL is ignored and the user is redirected to the default URL.  Has anybody else experienced this?  Is there anywhere else other than the header that I should be setting this?  I tried passing it in as a parameter but that didn't really work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying a embed userid in callback url then this post can help you.
You can save your oauth token in a session and later on callback you can retrieve user from session.

**on token request:**

```
def ask_access
  tumblr_consumer = get_consumer
  if tumblr_consumer
    #1. get a request token
    request_token = tumblr_consumer.get_request_token
    session[:request_token] = request_token
    session[:user_token] = "#{request_token.params[:oauth_token]}_#{current_user.id}"
    #2. have the user authorize
    redirect_to request_token.authorize_url
  else
    render :text=> "Failed to acquire request token from Tumblr."
  end
end
```

**on call back:**

```
def call_back
  if params[:oauth_token] && params[:oauth_verifier]
    request_token = session[:request_token]
    user_id  = session[:user_token].split("_")[1]
    user = UserProfile.find user_id
    ##3. get an access token
    access_token = request_token.get_access_token({:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier]})
    user.tumblr_token = access_token.params[:oauth_token]
    user.tumblr_secret = access_token.params[:oauth_token_secret]
    user.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, since Tumblr doesn't allow the callback url in the request header, this is the only solution.  Sorry for the very late accept :)

Answer (score 5):

According to [Tumblr's developer blog](http://developers.tumblr.com/post/32002964216/changelog-for-09-21-12), this was a bug in Tumblr's API and has been fixed.

> Many of you have been dismayed that you could not override the
>   callback url when a user was attempting to authorize their
>   application. Good news: we’ve patched the bug that was causing this
>   particular issue.
>
> Now, you can pass a url with the oauth_callback parameter and we will
>   redirect the user to that endpoint once you’re done.
>
> Let’s go over a quick example.
>
> When the user is presented with the screen to authorize your app, you
>   should be able to override your default callback with the
>   oauth_callback parameter in your url.
>
> http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=your_token&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com/oauth_callback/testing
>   The above url will redirect the user to
>   mysite.com/oauth_callback/testing and let you know if the user has
>   approved or denied your app.

**Update March 14, 2013**:

Starting today, Tumblr is no longer respecting the oauth_callback parameter. The blog post that I previously linked to has been deleted. I ended up using a variation of the accepted answer to work around it.

Answer (score 2):

Tumblr does this (I assume) for security. They require that the callback URL is defined on application registration and they will not let it be overridden during implementation.

The security issue is to make sure that no one can steal your Application Token and try to use it to use your reputation to get access to customer's data. By forcing all callbacks to go to the default URL, they can guarantee that only your application is able get the Access Tokens.

The two ways to handle this are:

1) Have the default URL do a redirect to where you want it to go based on cookie or some other data
2) Have different application tokens for different callback URLs.

Answer (score 2):

I can't respond to Jonathan Tran's answer, since my account is young, but posting the callback URL in the authorization URL no longer works, as he says. I asked on Twitter, and here was John Bunting's response:

https://twitter.com/codingjester/status/313248230987157505

I successfully was able to reroute my callback URL using the following (here in Python), after assigning all the proper keys:

```
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "POST", body=urllib.urlencode({"oauth_callback": "[your own URL here]"}))
```

Answer (score -1):

Tumblr implements this behavior differently from Twitter, so the same use of the Ruby OAuth library yields different results.

For your value of @callback_url, this works in Twitter:

```
  @request_token = @oauth.get_request_token({
    oauth_callback:@callback_url
  })
  redirect_to @request_token.authorize_url
```

But for Tumblr, you will be redirected to your default URL.  To specify a different URL, you should do this:

```
@request_token = @oauth.get_request_token
redirect_to @request_token.authorize_url + '&' + { oauth_callback:@callback_url }.to_query
```

This is consistent with their documentation/blog post (cited in another answer).  I have not checked to see if this is "correct" according to the OAuth 1.0a specification.